# Oauth.io service and social network linking, unlinking?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0

I'm using https://oauth.io/ service and I'm a little bit unlucky with finding correct documentation on few things:

1. Is it possible to unauthorize one or another social network from application? In other words destroy permissions for application to use user's settings of that network.
2. How do I make google plus oauth work:

There is an example for facebook:

```
OAuth.popup('facebook', function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        // do something with error
    }
    res.get('/me')
       .done(function(data) {
        alert('Hello ' + data.name)
    })
})
```

It does work for me but I can't figure out how can I make it work with google+ API. When I change provider to google_plus I manage to get authorization token but I'm not sure how to proceed further because calling res.get('/me') doesn't work ('I suppose /me is only for facebook API'). I've tried lots of different other urls that are for google+ but it seems that because G+ doesn't support CORS request it makes request to local oauthd server like so: `options.url = config.oauthd_url + '/request/' + options.oauthio.provider + options.url;` network returns that no such endpoint exists.

Please if anyone know how to solve this help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem too, and I found a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thyb/JMTVz/5/)

```
 res.get('/plus/v1/people/me').done(function (me) {
        $('#connect').slideUp('fast')
        $('#res').html(template({
            data: me
        })).slideDown('fast')

          res.get('/plus/v1/people/me/activities/public').done(function(activities) {
            $('#activities').html(activitiesTemplate({
                data: activities
            }))
        });
    })
```